# Tips on designing a shielded stepped linear resistance box

Tags: resistors, shielding, attenuator

I need a shielded, linear, stepped resistance for an experimental setup.

Requirements:

- 1000 Ohm to 1 MOhm
- Resistance accuracy is not of high concern: +-1000 Ohm is acceptable
- BNC in and out
- 50 kHz signal max, 2 Vpp max

With a 10 kHz - 50 kHz signal

- Low drift
- Very low noise

I am planing to build the circuit drawn below:

[image: Circuit]

It would use wire wound or metal film resistors, and small dip switches. I was planning to mount everything through-hole on a single layer PCB, and then mount it in a prebuilt shielded BNC project box like in the image below.

[image: Amazon box]

Questions:

1. Is there a better or more simplistic design that I could use? I am concerned by how long the signal path would be for higher resistances.
2. Are there any glaring issues with the design above? If so, what are they and how can I correct them?

Please respond with any additional information I could provide.

Comment: I have found a number of "decade resistance boxes" online but none of them have BNC I/O - even the expensive bench top ones. Maybe there is a fundamental reason for this that I don't understand...

Comment: You say that accuracy is "not of high concern" but then you ask for 0.1% accuracy (1k out of 1M). And what exactly does "Very low noise" mean...you need to put some numbers with that.

Comment: Just a note, that to get to 1MΩ you're going to need a third group of resistors (100k's) and the max value would be 999k (not exactly 1MΩ if that's relevant.)  For small signals, consider DIP switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those boxes don't have BNC because BNC implies certain signal integrity, and the decade resistance boxes are very low frequency devices. They are usually only specified for DC operation, and will perform adequately up to a couple hundred Hz, or within audio bandwidth. But even there the performance will vary as you go from lower to higher resistances, because these devices are not trimmed for AC, i.e. they don't have their parasitic capacitances compensated out.

So, you don't need a BNC. All you need is a BNC-to-banana adapter.

And if you really need the signal integrity you'd expect from a BNC-connected device, your best bet is to use a multiplying DAC as a programmable attenuator.

Finally: why do you need stepped resistance? Usually potentiometers are more useful than single resistors, so it'd help to know your application. Perhaps there are better solutions.

If I were to make one of those things, I'd be using reed relays for switching, and some pre-made ratio resistor networks, and a good LCR meter to characterize parasitics and trim them out. 10pF * 1MOhm is a time constant of 10us. That means you have low phase shift maybe out to 10kHz, and even that depends on how flat you need the response.

If you need it flat to 50kHz, it'll take some work.

As far as shielding integrity goes: usually you want to design a whole experimental setup to be coordinated in regards to shielding, and that's driven by concrete requirements. "Low noise" means nothing. Your low noise is not someone else's low noise. You need concrete numbers, driven by the application. If you don't understand the application well enough to have numbers, it'll help to dig deeper so you won't spend time acquiring equipment that's inadequate or overdesigned. It'd really help to know what this is plugged into, so that a matching shielding system can be set up. For example, if you need very low thermal DC errors or low DC leakage currents, you may need a doubly-shielded cable with a guard, with a matching bi-coaxial connector. But we don't know any of it yet...

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it in 1000 ohm steps and you don't need the switches to be in sequential steps you can do it with a binary progression of 10 resistances and 10 switches.

1000 ohms
2000 ohms
4000 ohms
8000 ohms
16000 ohms
32000 ohms
64000 ohms
128000 ohms
256000 ohms
512000  ohms

Since these are non-standard values you can use combinations of resistors in series or parallel to get values close to these.

Wire them all in series and have a switch across each one that shorts it when closed. By setting the switches to the right binary pattern you can get any multiple of 1000 up to 1,023,000
For example, if you want 134,000 you would open the switches for 128000, 4000, and 2000.

Comment: I think your solution would probably cost more, and possibly use more resistors, than what the OP proposed. You need precision resistors in either case, but for the OP's design you only need to buy 3 different values. Can you show an example design with actual values and tolerances that illustrates your approach?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well there's this: https://www.instructables.com/Binary-Resistance-Decade-Box/
Using 0.1% surface mount resistors you should be able to get each value using just 1 or 2 resistors. Even buying quantities of 1 they're not that expensive, and you'd only need 10 switches instead of 30.

Answer (score -1):

Closest thing I can think of is <s>this</s> building something like this Seven decade resistor <s>which I can only spot in Aliexpress</s>, which you could place inside the box.

It would produce less noise than having small dip switches for every step and metal wound resistors, as they are larger in size.

[image: seven decade resistor]

Image source [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001531094560.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.0.0.21ef18021Iq2bF)

It says it has 1% accuracy, and its on a small PCB, I cant think of anything else that would make it less "noisy".

Maybe by being a 4-layer PCB, so that it can have a GND plane? But I cant find such a product.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Hm lemme re-write the answer then.